# Constructor error message on test class for pagination

Tags: unit-test, class, pagination

I have a visual force page to display a list of locations. I used pagination and wrote class for it and working finely. but the test class is giving me an error :
Constructor not defined: [listView].(). Can you please help. 
Below is my code:

Constructor:

```
public class listView{

    ApexPages.StandardSetController con; 

  //controller


 public listView(ApexPages.StandardSetController con)
    {       

     this.con = con;

      con.setPageSize(20);   
     }   

    //Instantiate the StandardSetController   



    //Boolean to check if there are more records after the present displaying records   
    public Boolean hasNext   
    {   
        get   
        {   
            return con.getHasNext();   
        }   
        set;   
    }   

    //Boolean to check if there are more records before the present displaying records   
    public Boolean hasPrevious   
    {   
        get   
        {   
            return con.getHasPrevious();   
        }   
        set;   
    }   

    //Page number of the current displaying records   
    public Integer pageNumber   
    {   
        get   
        {   
            return con.getPageNumber();   
        }   
        set;   
    }   

    //Returns the previous page of records   
    public void previous()   
    {   
        con.previous();   
    }   

    //Returns the next page of records   
    public void next()   
    {   
        con.next();   
    }   
}
```

The Test class is:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)  
public class listViewTest {  

        public static testMethod void testlistView() {  
        PageReference pageRef = Page.DataCenterLocation;  
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page


        listView lv =new listView();

        lv.Next();


        lv.Previous();

        lv.con.getHasPrevious();
        lv.con.getHasNext();
        lv.con.getPageNumber();


     }

}
```

Comment: your testclass needs to use the listView constructor as defined in the ListView class - that is, it needs to be passed an instance of `ApexPages.StandardSetController`

Comment: is this how its going to be?

 listView lv =new listView(new ApexPages.StandardSetController());

Comment: it still giving me the same error

Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].<Constructor>() at line 11 column 35

Answer (score 1):

The [StandardSetController constructor documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_constructors.htm) shows that the constructor must have an argument. So in your test you will need to provide one. Here is one way:

```
@isTest  
public class listViewTest {  

    public static testMethod void testlistView() {

        ...

        Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'Account-' + i));
        }
        insert accounts;

        listView lv = new listView(new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accounts));

        ...
    }
}
```